# load_theme_textdomain path

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, translation, language

By default, WordPress loads the .mo file from **my-theme/languages** or **wp-content/langugages/themes**.

I need to add another path for WordPress in my plugin. For example, WordPress should load the .mo file from **wp-content/langugages/my-plugin/**.

Does anyone know the correct filter?

Answer (score 3):

After some more reseach, I found load_textdomain function which can help to load .mo file from any location.

load_textdomain($domain, $mofile);